# What is the best way to separate your code in a Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm working on a MEAN (Mongo Express.js Angular Node.js) CRUD application.  I have it working but everything is in one .js file.  The single source code file is quite large. I want to refactor the code so CRUD functionality is in different source code files.  Reading through other posts, I've got a working model but am not sure it is the right way in Node using Mongo to get it done.

Here's the code so far:

```
<pre>

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var db;
var connect = 'mongodb://<<mddbconnect string>>;
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

// viewed at http://localhost:<<port referecnes in app.listen>>
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

MongoClient.connect(connect, (err, database) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    db = database
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log('listening on 3000' + Date() );

    // Here's the require for the search function in another source code file.
    var searchroute = require('./serverSearch')(app, db);

    })
})

//Handlers
The rest of the CRUD application functions with app.post, app.get.  These are other functions I want to move into different source code files, like serverSearch.js.
</pre>
```

The code I separated right now is the search functionality which is inside of the MongoClient.connection function.  This function has to successfully execute to make sure the variable 'db' is valid before passing both variables 'app' and 'db' to the the search function built out in the source code file serverSearch.js.

I could now build out my other CRUD functions in separate files in put them in the same area as 'var searchroute = require('./serverSearch)(app,db);

Is this the best way to separate code in a MEAN application where the main app and db vars need to be instantiated then passed to functions in other source code files?

Answer (score 0):

What you are basically describing is modular coding heading towards "services" perhaps even micro-services. There are a few factors to keep in mind for your system. (I have no doubt that there are many other approaches to this btw). Basically in most NodeJS systems I have worked on (not all) I try to apply the following architecture in development and then bring over as much as possible I to production.

1. Create a directory under the main one. I usually use some type of name that points to the term functions. In this directory I maintain function and /or class files divided into categories. Function wrappers for DB would be held in DB functions. This file would **only** contain functions for the DB. Security functions in another file. Helper functions in another. Time manipulation in another. I am sure you get the idea. These are all wrapped in `module exports`

Now in any file in my project where say I would need DB and helpers I will start it by:

`let nhelpers = require("helpfuncs");`
`let ndb = require("dbfuncs");`

Obviously names are different. 
And btw I divide all the NPM packages in the same way under an environment directory.

Maintaining that kind of structure allows you to maintain sane order over the code, logical chaining in any decent IDE, and having relevant methods show up in your IDE without having to remember every function name and all the methods within. 
It also allows you to write an orderly system of micro-services making sure each part dies exactly what you want and allows for sane debugging.

It took me awhile to settle on this method and refine it. 
It paid off for me. Hope this helps.

Edit to clarify for the OP:

When it comes to the `process.env` variables I became a great fan of dotenv https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

This little package has saved me an incredible amount of headaches. Of course you will have to decide if you include it in production or not. I have seen arguments for both, but i think in a well set up AWS, Google, Azure environment (or in Docker of course) I am of the opinion it can safely be used. 
A couple of caveats.

1. Do not leave your dotenv file  in the root. Move it somewhere else in your directory structure. It is simple and I actually put it in the same directory as all my environment files and helper files.
2. Remember it is simply a text file. So an IDE will not pick  up your specific env variables in chaining. (Unless someone knows of a trick which I would love to hear about)
3. If you put env variables like access info to your DB system or other sensitive stuff, HASH THEM FIRST, put the hash in your env and have a function in your code which specifically just does the hash to the string. **Do not under any conditions leave sensitive information in your environment file without hashing it first.**
4. The final Gatcha. These are not PHP magic globals which cannot be overwritten. If you lose track and overwrite one of those process.env variables in your code it will take the new value until you restart your node app and it reads from the dotenv file again. (But then again that is the rule with all environment variables not only user defined ones)

Any typos above excuse me. Done from my cell in the train.

Comment: Thanks, do you share global variables?  And, I imagine you dbfuncs directory ends up with several micro-functions in separate files as well as some db operations in Mongo, by type you add error checking, can get quite long.

Comment: @Jef I will edit the answer above was thinking to include a part on env. variables.